# Gradle plugin openapitools.generator generateJavaClient is outputting source not a library client

Tags: java, gradle-plugin, openapi-generator

I have followed what I can find [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin) and [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md). See below code.

When I build, the output from this in ~/clients/java is source tree of files, *not a lib client* I was hoping to publish.  I can't see any other options within the plugin to specify otherwise.

What in my limited understanding of what i'm doing am i missing?

Do i need to generate from that ~/clients/java output? feels unnecessary.

```
task generateJavaClient(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
    generatorName = "java"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/infrastructure/modules/api-gateway/rest-api-definition.yaml"
    outputDir = "$buildDir/clients/java"
    packageName = "client_api"
    id = "client"
    logToStderr = true
    verbose = true
    generateAliasAsModel = false
    enablePostProcessFile = false
    version = getClientVersion(buildkiteBranch, buildkiteBuildNumber, buildkitePipelineDefaultBranch, buildkiteTag)
    configOptions = [
            artifactVersion: getClientVersion(buildkiteBranch, buildkiteBuildNumber, buildkitePipelineDefaultBranch, buildkiteTag)
    ]
}
```